# How to disconnect from multiple connected ble devices in Flutter app?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, bluetooth-lowenergy, dart-async

I am currently connected to multiple ble devices. Now, I'd like to disconnect from them but I can't.

Here's the code for connecting:

```
for (String deviceId in deviceIdList) {
  try {
     await Provider.of<BleDeviceConnector>(context, listen: false)
     .connectAndLoad(
     deviceId: deviceId, custom: custom, index: index);
   } catch (e) {
   print(e);
 }
}


// In separate file...

class BleDeviceConnector extends ReactiveState<ConnectionStateUpdate> {
  BleDeviceConnector({
    required FlutterReactiveBle ble,
    required Function(String message) logMessage,
  })   : _ble = ble,
        _logMessage = logMessage;

  final FlutterReactiveBle _ble;
  final void Function(String message) _logMessage;

  @override
  Stream<ConnectionStateUpdate> get state => _deviceConnectionController.stream;

  final _deviceConnectionController = StreamController<ConnectionStateUpdate>();

  late StreamSubscription<ConnectionStateUpdate> _connection;

  Future<void> connectAndLoad(
      {required String deviceId,
      required CustomModel custom,
      required int index}) async {
    _connection = _ble.connectToDevice(id: deviceId).listen((update) async {
      _deviceConnectionController.add(update);
      if (update.connectionState == DeviceConnectionState.connected) {
        await custom.loadCustomStuff();
      }
    }, onError: (e) {
      print('Connecting to device $deviceId resulted in error $e');
    });
  }

  Future<void> disconnect(String deviceId) async {
    try {
      print('disconnecting from device: $deviceId');
      _logMessage('disconnecting from device: $deviceId');
      await _connection.cancel();
    } on Exception catch (e, _) {
      print("Error disconnecting from a device: $e");
      _logMessage("Error disconnecting from a device: $e");
    } finally {
      // Since [_connection] subscription is terminated, the "disconnected" state cannot be received and propagated
      _deviceConnectionController.add(
        ConnectionStateUpdate(
          deviceId: deviceId,
          connectionState: DeviceConnectionState.disconnected,
          failure: null,
        ),
      );
      print("Disconnected from $deviceId");
    }
  }

  Future<void> dispose() async {
    await _deviceConnectionController.close();
  }
```

This results in connecting to all the devices in deviceList, and loading info.

However, when I then try to disconnect from all of connected devices, it only successfully disconnects from the last one that was written to.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
for (String deviceId in deviceIdList) {
  await Provider.of<BleDeviceConnector>(context, listen: false).disconnect(deviceId);
}
```

When I reached out to the package author (package: **flutter_reactive_ble**), he said:

*"you can create a class that will hold all subscriptions and then you can loop through them and cancel them one by one in order to disconnect"*

When I ran this by the discord, the thought was that I should make a list instead of a class (which seemed more along the lines of what I was thinking). Either way, I tried adding the **_connection** StreamSubscription to a list, but it doesn't even end up getting added to the list (for some reason).

They also mentioned to try and make another **_connection** variable since that appears to be the only one.

My understanding was that I would get a new instance every time I make a call to **connectAndLoad(...).

Any help would REALLY be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume only the last connection in the list is valid

Comment: I guess. But why and how would you suggest to fix it. All the devices are still connected. I can confirm that.